# Permission denied when running make install

Tags: 12.04, make

I'm trying to install llvm. I cloned the repository and ran ./configure. Now, I need to run `sudo make install`. When I run this, I get the following errors:

```
harshilsharma63@ubuntu:~/llvm$ sudo make install
[sudo] password for harshilsharma63: 
llvm[0]: Installing include files
make: execvp: /home/harshilsharma63/llvm/autoconf/mkinstalldirs: Permission denied
make: *** [install-local] Error 127
harshilsharma63@ubuntu:~/llvm$ sudo make install
llvm[0]: Installing include files
make: execvp: /home/harshilsharma63/llvm/autoconf/mkinstalldirs: Permission denied
make: *** [install-local] Error 127
```

I have installed build-essentials. I cloned the repository using svm in fedora and copied the downloaded files from Fedora -> Windows -> Ubuntu.

**Note: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like it's trying to execute a file `/home/harshilsharma63/llvm/autoconf/mkinstalldirs` but it doesn't have the permission to do this.
Just try to make this file runnable:

```
sudo chmod a+x /home/harshilsharma63/llvm/autoconf/mkinstalldirs
```

Then try to clean the make and do it again:

```
sudo make clean
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `chmod a+rx /home/harshilsharma63/llvm/autoconf/mkinstalldirs`